# htaccess rewrite a single url with variable to another

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite

`index.php/component/easydiscuss/tags?Itemid=1`

to

`easydiscuss1.htm`

The rule I used is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index.php/component/easydiscuss/tags?Itemid=1 easydiscuss1.htm [L]
```

However I just get a 404 for some reason even though this file is definitely on the server.

I think maybe the get parameters are causing a problem because I can rewrite urls without `GET` parameters like this fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

1. The query string can't be matched against in a rewrite rule, so the `?` in your regex pattern, is a regex `?` quantifier, meaning the `s` right after the "**tag**" is optional. Obviously, that's not what you want at all.
2. You are rewriting the URL **to** `/easydiscuss1.htm`, which means you will get a 404 unless the file `easydiscuss1.htm` is actually there. If it's there and you actually want to serve the file "easydiscuss1.htm" that's in your document root, then see #1 above.

Otherwise, you have the rule backwards. When you rewrite something, you take something the browser requests and you change that on the server. If you're changing it to something that's not there, then you should expect a 404 error. What you probably want is more along these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /index\.php/component/easydiscuss/tags\?Itemid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /easydiscuss%2.htm [L,R=301]
```

That will redirect the browser, telling it the resource that it requested is actually somwhere else. Then you need a rule to change the URL *back*:

```
RewriteRule ^/?easydiscuss([0-9]+)\.htm$ /index.php/component/easydiscuss/tags?Itemid=$1 [L]
```

---

EDIT

You need this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Itemid=1$
RewriteRule ^index.php/component/easydiscuss/tags$ easydiscuss1.htm [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your in depth answer.  I'm not looking for a dynamic matching rule.  I literally want to Rewrite a single URL.  I want to type http://mywebsite.com/index.php/component/easydiscuss/tags?Itemid=1 into the browser and have it serve http://mywebsite.com/easydiscuss1.htm  which is definitely there.  I'd already escaped the ? with a backslash in a previous attempt, but not the period, I'll try again.

Comment: @LucasScholten Ah, I edited the answer to cover the error in #1